# Add empty rows to results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add empty rows to results fetched from a select statement. For example, if the select query fetch 4 rows then 2 empty rows needs to be fetched. Objective should be the number of rows fetched should be 6 every time. The number of rows fetched will be 6 maximum if there are 6 rows with data.

Any idea?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If some part of your code is dependent on the amount of results, you should probably change the code instead

Comment: You should fix this in your code. If result has less then 6 rows then add required filler (empty) rows accordingly. Why would you want to break the way database work?

Comment: What database are you using Oracle,Sql Server, My Sql???

Comment: Im using MSSQL. I don't want to break the way of how db retrieve data but have to do it, because I'm using the select query to fetch records in SSRS. I'm unable to get it done through SSRS, so trying to get it from query level.

Answer (score 2):

In *SQL-SERVER* You can create temp table to update It with empty rows and you can use `WHILE` to insert desired number of rows with empty values. Something like:

```
-- Create temp table to update data with empty rows
CREATE TABLE #HoldEmptyRows
(
   Id NVARCHAR(20), 
   CustomerName NVARCHAR(20), 
   CustomerEmail NVARCHAR(20)
)

-- Insert data from SourceTable to temp
INSERT INTO #HoldEmptyRows
SELECT * FROM SourceTable

-- Do while count from temp table < of desired number insert empty rows
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM #HoldEmptyRows) < 6)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #HoldEmptyRows VALUES ('', '', '')
END

SELECT * FROM #HoldEmptyRows
```

---

**DEMO AT** <kbd>**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/027476/3)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try the below logic:

```
with cte as
(
select 0 as col1
union all
select col1+1 from cte where cte.col1<10
)

select * into #temp1 from cte


create table #test
(rownum int,col1 varchar(100))


declare @i int=1
while (@i<=6)
begin

insert into #test
select *   from 
(select row_Number() over (order by (Select 0))rownum, * from #temp1)x
where rownum=@i 

Set @i=@i+1
end
select case when rownum>4 then '' else col1 end as col1 from #test
```

Comment: I have created CTE just for the testing as per your requirement and inserted more then 6 record to verify the result.